# Shortcut for calculating the standard deviation of a binomial outcome?

Tags: binomial-distribution, standard-deviation

We can see the equations for [how to calculate the sample standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation), and perform these to the sample.

If our sample only ever consists of `0`s and `1`s, can we simplify the sample standard deviation calculation?

#### Example

If we have the 9 outcomes `0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0`

And we want to compute the standard deviation, we can perform the calculation manually which involves operating on each of the 9 elements in the sample (0.5270463).

But I wonder if we can avoid having to traverse each element since we know that the sample contains 5 `0`s and 4 `1`s -can we somehow reduce/simplify the calculation by using this knowledge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sample values are $y_1,...,y_n$ and $X$ is the sample count of $1$s (and writing $p=\frac{X}{n}$), the n-denominator variance of the sample is

\begin{eqnarray}
\text{var}_n(y_1,...,y_n) &=& \frac{1}{n}\sum_i (y_i-\bar{y})^2 \\ 
&=& (\frac{1}{n}\sum_i y_i^2)-\bar{y}^2 \\ 
&=& (\frac{1}{n}\sum_i y_i)-\bar{y}^2 \quad (\text{for 0/1 vars } y^2=y)\\ 
&=& \bar{y}-\bar{y}^2 \\ 
&=& X/n-(X/n)^2 \\ 
&=& X/n[1-(X/n)]\\
&=& p(1-p) 
\end{eqnarray}

To get a Bessel-corrected standard deviation, multiply by $\frac{n}{n-1}$ and take the square root.